# starting sshd: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: permission denied

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-web-services

I am running a Centos machine in Amazon cloud. Suddenly, I can't ssh into it. Fortunately, there is R Studio running that includes an ability to run BASH shell. So, I see in /var/log/boot.log that sshd failed to start.

When I run it from the command line `sudo service sshd start` I get an error that `Starting sshd: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: Permission denied`. I tried to set sshd_config permissions to either 644 or 600 - but I get the same error. Also I tried `sudo su -` and then start service.

And it is not the limitation of the shell itself: I can start httpd without any problems.

I don't even know what else to try...

Comment: what is the perms on /etc/ssh `ls -ld /etc/ssh`? Is it executable?

Comment: yes, 755 `drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Aug 24 02:05 /etc/ssh`

Comment: @Felix `sshd_config` should be chmoded to `600` or `u+rw,o=`. Make sure you check it using `ls -l sshd_config`  Also make sure that the problem is coming from `sshd_config` and not other misconfigured source.

Comment: verify that `sshd` did not lose its sticky bit, too

Comment: @sendmoreinfo - could you elaborate on it... I don't think sshd ever had sticky bit in the first place - why would you expect it to have it? Or maybe I misunderstand what you are saying

Answer (score 8):

I was faced with the same issue, and thanks to Felix answer, I could confirm that it was also an SELINUX error :

```
# grep "sshd_config" /var/log/audit/audit.log
...
type=AVC msg=audit(1585907328.579:143): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=1207 comm="sshd" name="sshd_config" dev="dm-0" ino=443439 scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=file
...
```

I was then able to solve the error by restoring the default contexts:

```
# restorecon /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

That way SELINUX didn't need to be disabled.

Answer (score 3):

This is what happened... There was a problem with the image (specifics here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=956531). So, as part of troubleshooting I mounted the EBS drive on a different machine, and "cleaned" sshd_config. *That* caused SELINUX to deny access to this file, and the error message was caused by SELINUX; not by file permissions. Once I disabled SELINUX, sshd came up fine.

World is saved :)